# Issue in getting the value from datagridview cell to put into decimal

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, decimal, cell

This is my code for my button that will pop the value from the specific column.

```
dvList.Columns("Reg_Price").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"

MsgBox(dvList.Rows(dvList.CurrentRow.Index).Cells.Item("Reg_Price").Value.ToString)
```

My value in the column "Reg_Price" is 0, when I click the button with the code above, the output is 0 also, I want the output to be 0.00, but the code above the msgbox is not working.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultCellStyle.Format` (and also cell format) operate only on the dataGridView display. When you get `dvList.Rows(dvList.CurrentRow.Index).Cells.Item("Reg_Price").Value.ToString`, you get the original cell, before formatting. You can use the vb.net `Format` function to format the numeric value for msgBox.

Comment: Ahh, now i get it why it only shows 0 and not with the decimal, Thank you for this information :)